# Question Editing tools appear to have died. Hacked?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I went to answer a question on SO and quickly discovered that the editing tools had disappeared!  They're also absent as I compose this.

The handy buttons for links, bold, etc., are gone.  Also shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl L</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl B</kbd>, etc. do not work.

No obvious errors in Firefox's error console (just the usual boatload of warnings that SO still generates).

But firebug breaks on this line of code in ***wmd.js*** (¡note the name!):
`var Attacklab=Attacklab||{};var Attacklab=Attacklab||{};Attacklab.showdown ...`

I fired up Chrome and it shows the same problem.

Anyone else see this?  Has SO been hacked or do I need to purge my system?

Also, tag search and auto-complete is busted.

Comment: Probably just a bug, not hacked. WMD is the live renderer.

Comment: i also faced this bug but solved when opened site in new browser window.

Comment: Did you try searching the web for the scary name? Attacklab is the creator of the javascript markdown code.

Comment: @Dan Grossman, no not yet.  First step was to determine if the problem was global or just on this machine.

Comment: It's affecting me, too. In Chrome and Opera.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson:  Thank you!   Nothing I've done, so far, has reset the problem, and I've only got one machine at this location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in some preview changes made to WMD to better match the server-side rendering, a build with a fix is being deployed across the network right now.  Meta's fixed now, other sites will be momentarily.

Comment: Fixed! That was quick!

Comment: Thanks, Nick!  I didn't see anything on any of [the blogs I'm aware of](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/).  Was the deployment announced somewhere?

Comment: @Brock - we build typically once or more a day, the blog will highlight major features...but many more minor or background things are being improved/added all the time with no fanfare :)

Comment: @Brock, there is a Community-maintained list of feature changed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange, although small things like you've pointed out won't be updated.